# Partial fraction integration problem

Tags: integration, partial-fractions

I'm trying to solve this integral by partial fraction:

$$
 \int \frac{2x-6} {(x-2)^2(x^2+4)} dx \
$$

i think i have to write the expression like

$$
 2\int \frac{x-3} {(x-2)^3(x+2)} dx \
$$

Then i don't know how i should resolve the partial fraction!

Comment: $-\frac{1}{4(x-2)^3}+\frac{5}{16(x-2)^2}-\frac{5}{64(x-2)}+\frac{5}{64(x+2)}$

Comment: Your first step is correct only if in the first integral you have $x^2-4$ at the denominator. Is it a typo?

Comment: If so, I'll adjust my answer. Did you mean $x^2+4$? I suppose so, as the denominator seems to have been fully factorized this way. If it was in fact $x^2-4$, your next step is alright.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Careful!

> $$
>  \int \frac{2x-6} {(x-2)^2(x^2+4)} dx \
> $$
>
> i think i have to write the expression like
>
> $$
>  2\int \frac{x-3} {(x-2)^3(x+2)} dx \
> $$

You seem to have replaced $x^2+4$ by $(x-2)(x+2)$, but these are not the same! You might be confusing with $x^2\color{red}{-}4=(x-2)(x+2)$...

You can take out the (constant) factor $2$, but you don't have to. For the partial fraction decomposition, you're looking for numbers $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$ such that:
$$\frac{2x-6} {(x-2)^2(x^2+4)} = \frac{A}{x-2} + \frac{B}{(x-2)^2} + \frac{Cx+D}{x^2+4} $$
Once you have that, the integral splits into these three terms and these are all easy to integrate.

I can elaborate on the partial fraction decomposition; unless you can take it from here?

---

For the partial fraction decomposition:

$$\begin{array}{rl}
\displaystyle \frac{2x-6} {(x-2)^2(x^2+4)}
 & \displaystyle = \frac{A}{x-2} + \frac{B}{(x-2)^2} + \frac{Cx+D}{x^2+4} \\[7pt]
 & \displaystyle = \frac{A(x-2)(x^2+4)+B(x^2+4)+(Cx+D)(x-2)^2}{(x-2)^2(x^2+4)} \end{array}$$

Now equating the numerators:
$$2x-6 = A(x-2)(x^2+4)+B(x^2+4)+(Cx+D)(x-2)^2$$

**Method 1**

You can expand the RHS and group per power of $x$ and then identify the corresponding coefficients left and right; this gives you four linear equations in the 4 unknown variables.

$$2x-6 = (A+C)x^3+(-2A+B-4C+D)x^2+(4A+4C-4D)x+(-8A+4B+4D)$$

Which gives the system:
$$\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
A+C & = &  0  \\
-2A+B-4C+D & = &  0  \\ 
4A+4C-4D & =&  2  \\ 
-8A+4B+4D & = & -6
\end{array} \right. \quad \Rightarrow  \quad
\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
A & = &  \tfrac{3}{8}  \\
B & = &  -\tfrac{1}{4} \\ 
C & =&  -\tfrac{3}{8}  \\ 
D & = & -\tfrac{1}{2}
\end{array} \right.$$

**Method 2**

It is indeed also possible to simplify by choosing handy values for $x$ to substitute into
$$2x-6 = A(x-2)(x^2+4)+B(x^2+4)+(Cx+D)(x-2)^2$$

For example:

- Substitution of $x=2$ yields $-2=8B$ so $B = -\tfrac{1}{4}$.
- Substitution of $x=0$ yields $-6=-8A+4B+4D$ so $8A-4D=5$.
- (...)

If you know complex numbers, substitution of $x = 2i$ gives you $C$ and $D$ immediately, then $A$ follows from $8A-4D=5$.

Comment: Ok, now i'm trying to solve A,B,Cx and D;
If i put: x=2 i get B= -1/4 , then for x=0 i get -5=-8A-2D ,and i don't know what i've to do

Comment: Alright; note that you're just looking for the coefficient $C$, not $Cx$. Let me know if you have trouble with solving this.

Comment: I know how to solve this when i only have A,B,C , but with 4 i can't follow after i solve the A

Comment: I edited my answer.

Comment: Using the 2nd method, wich valor of x should i put in the 3rd substitution? , i think the idea is using (5+4D)/8 as A , then using 0 as x another time?

Comment: You can take any value, but some will give you easier equations. Due to the factor $x^2+4$, you won't get "very easy" equations if you only use real numbers.

Comment: i can't use complex numbers in this exercise, i will try to resolve without. Thank you!

Comment: Alright! If you combine the easy $B$ (method 2) together with the general approach (method 1: 4x4 system), substitution of $A+D=0$ and knowledge of $B$ leaves you with a simple 2 by 2 system.